# Why do I see fixed horizontal lines on my desktop?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati

I've just installed Ubuntu on my computer and there is something wrong on my desktop. 
This is an image of the problem (look at the top):

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

My graphics card is an ATI Radeon X1250; I read the drivers are no longer supported in Ubuntu 11.10 and I think I have the free drivers. I have no idea of what to do!

Comment: Do you get the same issue in Unity 2D?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue

Comment: Having the same issue on the same card.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).